# Bootstrap-3 Meteor event on radio buttons

Tags: javascript, radio-button, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm trying to get the event click on radio buttons (meteor).

I'm doing in the template events (client js file):

```
Template.Questions.events({
 'click #public_btn' : function (){
  console.log('1');
  // something
 },

 'click #private_btn' : function (){
  console.log('2');
  // something
 }
```

and in the html client file I have the radio buttons:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="radio" name="privacy_options" value="public" id="public_btn"> Public
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="privacy_options" value="private" id="private_btn"> Private
    </label>
  </div>
```

The thing is the `click` event does not fire as long ad the `div` got the `data-toggle="buttons"`

Is there a way to fox this ?

Comment: It should not be something like this `$('#public_btn').click(function (){});`

Comment: @SumanBogati while you can use this jquery style of defining events its not very good because when you change templates/switch route it wont work anymore

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note, that as of Meteor 0.8, Template events will work correctly with jQuery triggered events.

So the correct solution will be just binding to the `change` event:

```
Template.Questions.events({
  'change #public_btn' : function (){
   console.log('1');
  // something
 },

'change #private_btn' : function (){
   console.log('2');
   // something
}
```

---

First up, the event will actually be the `change` event on the `input:radio` (not `click` at the time of writing)

Second of all, Meteor (0.7.0) uses it's own events engine, which wont catch jQuery triggered events eg. `$(element).trigger('change')`

If you take a look at the [bootstrap source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/button.js#L62) it shows that the `toggle` buttons fires a jQuery / synthetic event.

So you need to bind jQuery event handlers, the most efficient way that I've found, is to do it on template creation - but based off `document.body` rather than the actual element - as it will be replaced on each render.

```
Template.Questions.created = function(){
  // must bind to `document.body` as element will be replaced during re-renders
  // add the namespace `.tplquestions` so all event handlers can be removed easily
  $(document.body).on('change.tplquestions', '#public_btn', function(e){
     // handler
  });
  // add the namespace `.tplquestions` so all event handlers can be removed easily
  $(document.body).on('change.tplquestions', '#private_btn', function(e){
     // handler
  });
 };
 Template.Questions.destroyed = function(){
   // remove all event handlers in the namespace `.tplquestions`
   $(document.body).off('.tplquestions');
 }
```

Comment: Widh I could up your answer twice. It's clear and useful, thx for taking the time :)